# How to replace in a string character (latin-1) 'ē' whose code is u0113 with 'e' (code UTF-8:u0065)

Tags: python-2.7

How to replace in a string character (latin-1) **'ē'** whose code is u0113 with **'e'** (code UTF-8:u0065)

I get the foolowing python error:

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

`str.decode("utf-8").replace(u"\u0113", "e")`